# ASP.NET ControllerBase Extension Method Doesn't Work on Razor View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I've created extension method like below

```
public static class RBACExtension
{
    public static bool HasPermission(this ControllerBase controller, string permission)
    {
       // some implementation 
    }
}
```

It works fine inside a controller

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        this.HasPermission("somePermission");
        return View();
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work inside Razor. When I want to use the method it doesn't show up on autocomplete.

```
ViewContext.Controller.HasPermission("somePermission")
```

How to make it available inside Razor view?

Comment: Have you referenced the namespace where your static `RBACExtension` class is located ?

Comment: @Fabjan ahh that's the problem, thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

put extension method in a namespace like

```
namespace mynamespace.extensions{
public static class RBACExtension
{
    public static bool HasPermission(this ControllerBase controller, string permission)
    {
       // some implementation 
    }
 }
}
```

and put a using statement at top of your view like

```
@using mynamespace.extensions
```

Then this method will be available in your view

Comment: ahh that's the problem, my bad. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

`ViewContext.Controller` is the `Controller` class, not your base controller class. This is a bit of an awkward way to do this though as it couples your controllers to your views. Instead make an extension method (as a custom HtmlHelper is a great way), for exmaple:

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static bool HasPermission(this HtmlHelper helper, string permission)
    {
        // blah
    }
}
```

And use in Razor like this:

```
@Html.HasPermission("admin")
```

Alternatively put the method in a class inherited from `WebViewPage` for use in your Razor view. For example:

```
public abstract class MyBaseViewPage : WebViewPage
{
    public bool HasPermission(string permission)
    {
        // blah
    }
}
```

Then make your Razor pages use it by editing your `Views/web.config`

```
<pages pageBaseType="YourProject.MyBaseViewPage">
```

And now in Razor you can simply do this:

```
@HasPermission("admin")
```